# prevent user creating a duplicate node title

Tags: nodes

how to prevent user creating a duplicate node title for a content type?

I already try uniqueness module (https://drupal.org/project/uniqueness) but it's only list out the duplicate content title but not return any error message when user save the new content. Any suggestion module or code? :)

Comment: have you looked at https://drupal.org/project/unique_field ?

Comment: @Jimajamma ,good suggestion (y).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Unique field](https://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module.

> This module performs additional validation when a node is created or
>   updated by a user to require that a node's title, author, language,
>   and CCK fields are unique within a given context.

I have not tested it yet, but it seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of two coding approaches:

1. Use hook_node_validate()
2. Call '#validate' in form alter

We should not validate inside hook_node_insert() or, hook_node_presave()

You can make use of code like below:

```
  $type = 'Content_Type_Machine_Name_You_Want_To_Validate_For';

  if (YOUR_CONDITION_FOR_CONTENT_TYPE_CHECK) {  
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $node_title_exists =  $query->fields('n', array('nid'))
      ->condition('n.type', $type, '=')
      ->condition('n.title', 'SUBMITTED_NODE_TITLE', '=')
      ->execute()
      ->fetchField();
    if ($node_title_exists) {
      // WRITE form_set_error();    
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is node title validation
https://www.drupal.org/project/node_title_validation